# Retrieve json from the SOAP api call

Tags: ios, json, swift, soapui

I am new to SOAP .when i make api call i got the following response(json object inside XML) using postman.

```
<string xmlns="http://*******/">
{"Id":0,"NumberType":null,"Number":null,"FullName":null}
</string>
```

I tried to use Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

```
  Alamofire.request(common.getURL(), method: .post,parameters: ["strId": "1"], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: NetworkingUtil.getAlamoFireHeader()).responseJSON { (Response) in
        let error = Response.result.error
        let req = Response.request
        let res = Response.response
        let json = Response.data
        if error != nil {
            if req != nil && res != nil {
                print(req!)
                print(res!)
            }
        }else{
            var parsedjson : JSON!;
            do {
                parsedjson = try JSON(data : json!)
                print(parsedjson!)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Output

```
    {
     "d" : "{\"Id\":0,\"NumberType\":null,\"Number\":null,\"FullName\":null}"
    }
```

how i can extract json object from response?
Is there any standard library for iOS swift,can i use Alamofire for this purpose?
I could not be able to find a good solution for swift.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to use it in SoapUI as it is tagged?

Comment: Thanks Rao.I am searching for a good solution

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in soapUI or groovy?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar once, only not with AlamoFire or Postman. This what I did to get the JSON:

```
func downloadJSON(_ completion:  @escaping (_ result: AnyObject?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void ) -> URLSessionDataTask {
    // build url and submit for data in order

    let url = Client.URLFromParameters(Client.Constants.Parse.Scheme, Client.Constants.Parse.Host, Client.Constants.Parse.Path, withPathExtension: Client.Constants.Methods.StudentLocation , withQuery:  "?order=-updatedAt")

    return Client.sharedInstance().doAllTasks(url: url, task: "GET", jsonBody: "", truncatePrefix: 0, completionHandlerForAllTasks:  completion)

}
```

// Client.sharedInstance().doAllTasks() did the URLTask and returned the data through the completion handler. The important bit occurred in the convertDataWithCompletionHandler() listed below:

```
private func convertDataWithCompletionHandler(_ data: Data, completionHandlerForConvertData: (_ result: AnyObject?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {

        var parsedResult: AnyObject! = nil
        do {
            parsedResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject
        } catch {
            let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Could not parse the data as JSON: '\(data)'"]
            completionHandlerForConvertData(nil, NSError(domain: "convertDataWithCompletionHandler", code: 1, userInfo: userInfo))
        }
        completionHandlerForConvertData(parsedResult, nil)
    }
```

Then to read the objects I did this:

```
func getLocations(completed: @escaping (_ error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    // try to download data and scrub it
    // on success store in array of locations
    downloadJSON({ (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            completed(error)
        } else {
            let locationsDict = result?["results"] as! [[String : Any]]
            for item in locationsDict {
                // MARK: REVISIT
                var newLocation = StudentLocation(studentLocation: item)
                if let dstring = item["updatedAt"] as? String {
                    newLocation.updatedAt = self.getDate(date: dstring)
                    //self.locations.append(newLocation)
                    StudentDataSource.sharedInstance.studentData.append(newLocation)
                }
            }
        }
        print(result)
        self.sortLocations {
            //print(self.locations.description)
        }
        completed(nil)
    })
}
```

The section that I think you'll need to use is

```
let locationsDict = result?["results"] as! [[String : Any]]
```

Comment: For you (I believe) it would be let dictionaryOfParsedJSON = parsedJSON["d"] as! [[String:Any]]